# Spring Reactive Programming Repeat

Tags: reactive-programming

I have a simple scenario which i am unable to code using reactive programming

I have a serviceA which return someresponse which is then passed to a validator method,
this validator method can return 3 possible values as Enum each for

1. validationSuccessful
2. validationError
3. RetryServiceA

If returned enum is retryServiceA , then i need to recallServiceA, else if there is validation error I need to call serviceB and merge response of service A(passed and param) and serviceB and return the response

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: regarding "If returned enum is retryServiceA , then i need to recallServiceA" --> What's the expected behavior ?? Just call service A just one more time or keep retrying service A ?? If its just one more time.. what's the behavior if there's a timeout or business error ??